# Spring boot 406 error using APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM

Tags: spring, spring-boot

my code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/v1/files")
public class FileController {
    @Autowired
    FileService fileService;

    @GetMapping(value="/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile(@PathVariable Integer id, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        FileInfo file = fileService.getFile(id);

        String dispositionPrefix = "attachment; filename=";
        String encodedFilename = file.getOrgName();
        Path filePath = Paths.get(file.getPath(), file.getName());
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(Files.newInputStream(filePath, StandardOpenOption.READ));

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentLength(Files.size(filePath))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, dispositionPrefix + encodedFilename)
                .body(resource);
    }
}
```

And I get `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`

I set content type with `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`. But I don't know what goes wrong...

I tried to download `JPG` files name like `*************.jpg` such as `1542293055613.jpg`

Comment: If you want to downoad JPG why not use `MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE`? In any case try by using `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

There was no proper `HttpMessageConverter` for my spring project. I just added `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`, then it works.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter(true));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This posted code is correctly. I run it without error.

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

This Exception thrown when the request handler cannot generate a response that is acceptable by the client.

Please check your request from client.